# Calculating a total price with group pricing

Tags: php

I'm evaluating a `meeting_type` value that determines what kind of pricing structure I should be using. Currently, if my `meeting_type` value is a `w`, we charge one price for every 10 registrants. If the `meeting_type` is anything else, it's a price per registrant model.

I'm using this logic:

```
if($_POST['meeting_type'] != 'w'){          
    $total_price = $guests * $price;
}
else{
    $webinar_count = ceil($guests / 10);
    $total_price = $webinar_count * $price;
}
```

Is this logic flawed?  Can it be improved upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Removing intermediate variable `$webinar_count`**

```
$total_price = ($_POST['meeting_type'] == 'w')
             ? (ceil($guests / 10) * $price)
             : ($guests * $price);
```

OR

```
if ($_POST['meeting_type'] != 'w') {
    $total_price = $guests * $price;
} else {
    $total_price = ceil($guests / 10) * $price;
}
```